# how does mysql select for update works

Tags: mysql, transactions

As is said in [innodb locking reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) `For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows`.

first I create a table `person` which only has two record

```
mysql> select * from person;
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | age  |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | tom   |   21 |
|  2 | jerry |   10 |
+----+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

then I tried:

```
Sess1 mysql> start transaction;
             select * from person where name='tom' for update;
      +----+------+------+
      | id | name | age  |
      +----+------+------+
      |  1 | tom  |   21 |
      +----+------+------+ 
      -- id is a primary key
Sess2 mysql> start transaction;
             update person set age=11 where id=2;  -- it's blocking!
```

I use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to get lock type which is `RECORD LOCK ont gap`

```
---TRANSACTION 1835, ACTIVE 300 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 6, OS thread handle 140680312538880, query id 358 172.17.0.1 root updating
update person set age=11 where id=2
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1835, sees < 1834
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 5 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 24 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `test`.`person` trx id 1835 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000002; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000070d; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2b0000013e0110; asc +   >  ;;
 3: len 5; hex 6a65727279; asc jerry;;
 4: len 4; hex 8000000a; asc     ;;
```

I question is why in `Sess2` the update statement was blocked? I think `Sess1` only hold the lock `id = 1`

Comment: The key is *index entries*, I presume. You don't have an index for `name`, do you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yep, so you mean that `Sess1` hold the lock of `index` not the `row`？I change statement in `Sess1` to `select name from person where id = 1 for update;` then `Sess2` not  blocked